# Can tomcat store variables/properties that get called from a war

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, ant, war

I want to be able to deploy my app using ANT to Tomcat.

I don't want the process to be any different for dev and prod. However the two use different databases i.e. myapp and myapp-dev

How can I make this happen? Can I store a variable in the different tomcat containers and make the application call the name of the database from Tomcat.

Or if what I am asking is ridiculous what is the generally accepted way to achieve deploying to dev and prod with the same process.

Comment: I've previously used settings in `catalina.properties`. Those will be set as system properties and can be queried by your application. If you can make your configuration depend on a system property then an entry such as `myapplication.deploy.type=prod` or `...=dev` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

The generic way is to put the configuration string in a JNDI entry.

If JNDI is not a possible solution, then a property file in the right location (so it shows up in the classpath of the WAR files) is also useful, but needs careful documentation.

Have you considered letting the web container manage the database connection pool, so you only need a single one pr container, which then can be retrieved through JNDI?

Comment: The purpose of JNDI is clearly to decorrelate the object representing a configuration and its content. You should use JNDI ! ;)

Comment: Plain Web containers are not _required_ to provide JNDI.

Comment: @ZNK-M Tomcat is just a single servlet container - I do not believe it provides the Java EE Web Profile yet - of many, and hence it introduces a subtle vendor dependency.

Comment: @Thorjorn  I am using jndi on my project to retrieve the datasource. It is configured once and shared across all the project and servlets deployed on the server. Here is the doc: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html I don't understand what you mean by "single servlet container". Hopefully you can deploy dozen of servlet in a tomcat instance.

Comment: @ZNK-M the moment your web container go outside the servlet spec (which I assume you are familiar with) with Java EE technologies like JNDI you essentially become vendor dependent

Comment: @thorjorn definitely, but I think we can consider the JNDI technology is widely used and implemented by most of the the serlvet container. There isn't that much risk using it.

Comment: @ZNK-M Please be more careful when reading what I have written.  I am  not saying that JNDI should not be used, but that it is outside the servlet specification so you rely on vendor specific extensions.  As long as you are perfectly fine with that, great, but it means that you cannot deploy directly to a servlet container not providing JNDI (like plain Jetty).   You may want to investigate the world outside the Tomcat eco system, because Java EE is a _lot_ more and you need to know things like this.